# How to Remove a node when node on top is removed spritkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have 2 nodes as shown in figure. The node above (`SKLabelNode`) is child to the node below (`SKSpriteNode`). When I touch the `SKLabelNode` both node should be removed from the scene, but now just the label node is getting removed, Can you please suggest how to remove the node below when I touch the node above?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Name your nodes and enumerate this when appropriate (in swift):

```
 let nodes = ["button", "label"]
 for string in nodes {
   enumerateChildNodesWithName(string) {
     node, stop in
     node.removeFromParent()
   }
 }
```

obj-c example:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"button" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    // remove the button node from your scene
    [node removeFromParent];
  }];
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"label" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    // remove the label node from your scene
    [node removeFromParent];
  }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ..I am not familiar with swift, can you please give objective c code ..Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without the code you are using to remove the node and the code used to create the nodes. I am guessing you are using the standard touches begin method and just getting the node at point. If that is the case you may want to check what node you are actually touching.

```
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
 SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

 if ([node isKindOfClass:[SKLabelNode class]])
 {
    [node.parent removeFromParent];
 }
 else
 {
    [node removeFromParent];
 }
```

However if your nodes have names (and this would be safer) you would be better off checking the name first...

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"label"])
{
    [node.parent removeFromParent];
}
else if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"button"])
{
    [node removeFromParent];
}
```